# Can't update the date type in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to retrieve the date of birth from users once they submit the form and update the date type, but I am unable to update the date type. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
if($_POST){
    $dob = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['year']."-". $_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day'])); 

    $retur = $userObj->updateProfile($dob);
}

 public function updateProfile($dob){
$db = db_mysql::getInstance();
$qr = $db->query("UPDATE ".USERS." SET dob = $dob WHERE id = '".$udata."'") or die(mysql_error()); 

        return $udata;
}
```

Comment: Whats the mysql error returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$qr = $db->query("UPDATE ".USERS." SET dob = '$dob' WHERE id = '".$udata."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

You should look at using bound parameters, though - it avoids this sort of thing, as well as making your code a lot more secure.

Editted to add:

[The manual page on binding parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)  has a few very useful examples.

Comment: that seemed to have worked... I will look into bound parameters. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of a bound parameter or link?

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around the date, now the statement looks like

```
UPDATE USERS SET dob = 01-02-2012 WHERE id = 'x'
```

The date in this case is seen as a number (-2013, I think). ;)

Even better: Use prepared statements (search for PDO) and pass the date in a date parameter.

Comment: How can it be seen as a number if I used strtotime()?

Answer (score 1):

What is $udata and where are you getting it from?

If it is a class property then you need to call it with `$this->udata` or `$db::udata` in this case since you seem to be calling a static class or perhaps pass it in to the function if it is neither of these.

Also why is your query `"UPDATE ".USERS." SET dob = $dob WHERE id = '".$udata."'"`, what is happening with USERS? Sure it should just be `"UPDATE USERS SET dob = '$dob' WHERE id = '".$udata."'"` and add the '' around $dob as mentioned previously.